# Product version of Azure SQL Managed Instance

Tags: azure-sql-managed-instance

`xp_msver[ProductVersion]` and `SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')` do not return same version for Azure SQL Managed Instance. Shouldn't those two be the same?

Answer (score 1):

Values are different since this is cloud database running with V12 edition. As [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance) states Managed instance is a new deployment option of Azure SQL Database, providing near 100% compatibility with the **latest SQL Server on-premises (Enterprise Edition)** Database Engine. Here is [more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance#how-to-programmatically-identify-a-managed-instance) about it:

[image: []

Always refer to compatibility level. Read more about compatibility certification [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/compatibility-certification?view=sql-server-ver15).

Compatibility certification allows businesses to upgrade and modernize a SQL Server database on-premises, in the cloud, and on the edge, eliminating risks of application compatibility.

The same Database Engine powers both SQL Server and Azure SQL Database (including Managed Instance). This shared Database Engine means that a user database can be moved seamlessly between on-premises SQL Server and Azure SQL Database, while the application code that executes in the database as Transact-SQL continues to work as it would in its source system.